# Jquery when do you use $.get(index) instead normal selector

Tags: jquery

Just wondering when do you actually use $.get(index); I am a bit confused on when and where to use $.get(index), when u can straight get any element by getting the id or class name?

(note i am not talking about the $.get() ajax call) sorry i confused some of your guys

Comment: `$.get()` is used to make AJAX calls; are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: use of $.get in jquery is to **Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request** . **.get() and jQuery.get() are different**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state, [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) retrieves the DOM object, not the jQuery object. So if you need the native DOM object, you'd use .get().

Why would you need the native DOM element? For example, you might want to access methods like .play() on an HTML5 video.

`$('#myvideo').play()` wouldn't work. `$('#myvideo').get(0).play()` would.

Comment: **$('#myvideo').play() wouldn't work. $('#myvideo').get(0).play() would.** ? why is that? by the way im not the one who downvoted ur answer bro.

Comment: Because `.play()` is a method available on the *native* DOM object, not jQuery's object.

Answer (score 1):

Say you had a list with no id's or classes but wanted to target the middle list item:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

You could then use:

```
$('li').get(1)
```

to retrieve list item two (index is zero based)

Answer (score 0):

The $.get function in jQuery is for making Ajax calls, not selecting elements. Please see this in the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: It's confusing, but `get` with a single integer parameter can be used to return the raw DOM element from the collection.

Comment: I was not familiar with that method - thanks for pointing it out! Can it be called on the base jQuery object as well as on a jQuery collection?

Comment: Only as a collection. I've seen people frequently call `get` really wanting `load`, because they're thinking about `$.get`.